# Gson deserialisation generates NULL value

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

I was trying to read and convert a JSON file to an array but getting null values from the array after reading the JSON file. I am using the default constructor for my `ShipDetail` class.

```
  BufferedReader detailReader = new BufferedReader( new  FileReader(shipDetails));
  // Buffered passed to convert json array to java array
  ShipDetail[] shipDetail  = gson.fromJson(detailReader, ShipDetail[].class );

  System.out.println( shipDetail[0].toString());

  // Convert  array to arrayList
  ArrayList<ShipDetail> detailArray = new ArrayList<ShipDetail>(Arrays.asList(shipDetail));
```

The JSON file:

```
[  
   {  
      "idmessage":"27301",
      "idsession":"362",
      "time_stamp_system":"2017-01-20 14:51:14",
      "NMEA_string":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "processed":"1",
      "MMSI":"0000000001",
      "AIS_version":"0",
      "IMO_number":"xxxxxxxxxx",
      "callSign":"ODLK1",
      "name":"ODLXJ KWW",
      "type_of_ship_and_cargo":"0",
      "bow_to_possition_unit":"212",
      "stern_to_possition_unit":"71",
      "port_to_possition_unit":"22",
      "starboard_to_possitio_unit":"22",
      "type_of_position_fixing_divice":"1",
      "ETA":null,
      "destination":"",
      "last_static_draught":"0",
      "DTE":"127"
   }
]
```

The `ShipDetail` class:

```
public class ShipDetail {

    private String IdMessage, IdSession, Time_Stamp_System, Nmea_String, Processed;
    private String Mmsi, Ais_Version, Imo_Number, Callsign, Name, Type_Of_Ship_And_Cargo;
    private String Bow_To_Position_Unit, Stern_To_Position_Unit, Port_To_Position_Unit, Starboard_To_Position_Unit,
            Type_Of_Position_Fixing_Device;
    private String Eta, Destination, Last_Ship_Draught, Dte;

    public String getMmsi() {
        return Mmsi;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n Id Message : " + IdMessage + "\n Id Session : " + IdSession + "\n Time Stam System : "
                + Time_Stamp_System + "\n NMEA String : " + Nmea_String + "\n Processed : " + Processed + "\n MMSI : "
                + Mmsi + "\n AIS Version : " + Ais_Version + "\n IMO Number : " + Imo_Number + "\n Call Sign : "
                + Callsign + "\n Name : " + Name + "\n Type Of Ship And Cargo : " + Type_Of_Ship_And_Cargo
                + "\n Bow To Position Unit : " + Bow_To_Position_Unit + "\n Stern To Position Unit : "
                + Stern_To_Position_Unit + "\n Port To Position Unit : " + Port_To_Position_Unit
                + "\n Starboard To Position Fixing Device : " + Starboard_To_Position_Unit
                + "\n Type Of Position Fixing Device : " + Type_Of_Position_Fixing_Device + "\n ETA : " + Eta
                + "\n Destination : " + Destination + "\n Last Ship Draught : " + Last_Ship_Draught + "\n DTE : " + Dte;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the json file. Also how ShipDetail looks, does it have constructors, get and set methods, did you override toString method so you wannted to use it?

Comment: I was using default constructor and I have overridden toString( ) method.

Comment: You need to generate getters and setters also. Your fileds are `private`. Also when mapping things directly to an Object you need to have getters and setters most libraries required them.

Comment: Is it same as declaring public instead of private ?

Comment: No. The implementation of the custom libraries that maps SQL or JSON or XML to java objects are looking for GET and SET methods. That is the way they are implemented. They do something like: `object.setField1(someValue)` not `object.field1 = someValue`.

Comment: @lazarov Gson maps values directly to the fields ignoring accessors. This is the way it was designed.

Comment: Yes @LyubomyrShaydariv you are correct I just read about it: GSON does not use them. I have expirience with other types of libs which require setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Gson mapping does not match the given JSON. By default, Gson maps JSON properties to their appropriate fields in the target mapping by *exact* name. Take a look at:

```
"idmessage":"27301"
```

and

```
private String IdMessage
```

The property name case and the field name case do not match. What you need is map your JSON correctly. Either:

```
private String idmessage
```

or by overriding the name match (and that's more appropriate for the Java naming conventions):

```
@SerializedName("idmessage")
private String idMessage;
```

Note one field per line. This is required in order to annotated each field separately. Or, if possible, use camelCase both in Java and JSON.

Comment: @Anny If this answer solves your problem please do not forget to accept and vote on it.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: but only thing I am not getting is what's the difference between declaring String one's for all variables  and declaring String type for each variable. Why does Libraries require in such way?

Comment: @Anny 1: it increases the code readability very much. 2: An annotated declaration would affect _all_ fields in the declaration as if the annotated was applied to each field, thus Gson would throw an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class ShipDetail declares multiple JSON fields named idmessage`.

Comment: Thanks very much :

Comment: @Anny one more plus for keeping a single property per a declaration: version-tracking systems like Git, SVN and so forth use line-by-line differences algorithms to track the content changes. Thus, if you keep everything in a single line, the diffs would be ugly. But once you keep everything apart, your diffs would be easier to read and easier to merge if necessary, because if there are changes to the _same_ line in two branches, merging them would cause text conflicts that are not a pleasure to fix having too many fields. Just a pragmatic point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along these lines. Note that you don´t have to use `Files.readAllBytes` but in your code it could also be that the `BufferedReader` causes the error. If you need your `ShipDetails` as Array instead of a list, convert it or use your needed type in the `TypeToken`.

```
final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
final Gson gson = builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();

// you can use the buffered reader here too, but this is easier to debug if shipDetails is a file
final String jsonRepresentation = new String(Files.readAllBytes(shipDetails);

// add a type definition
final Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ShipDetail>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<ShipDetail> shipDetails = gson.fromJson(jsonRepresentation, type);
```

And as mentioned in the comments above, generate Getters and Setters.